# Early 2000s sci-fi (thriller?) movie?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie when I was a little kid so my memory of it is kinda messy. And I'm not sure if I remember it correctly.

But I remember the movie was set inside a building or office building, something like that. And the characters in it were being hunted by one person, who then would shoot them. But they could be hunting each other, I'm not sure.

There are two characters that I remember vividly, one of them is a guy wearing helmet, Daft Punk helmet, or something similar.

And one of them is grungy/emo/goth girl and there's one scene where she was peeing in the building's toilet. And I think she has a pink hair, and stripped knee length socks, but I could be remembering wrong.

And somehow I remember something about (big) cable being connected to them or one of the character, and if it were pulled, that person would die. But my memory is all jumbled up and I could be remembering two different movie.

And somehow, for whatever reason, I think it's british movie. But again.. my memory about it is vague, I'm not even sure whether it's a movie or I just have a wild dream.

Comment: The cable pull makes me think of this; https://youtu.be/lEJufm6reF0?t=224

Comment: Oh yeah, I remember The Matrix had the same thing. Damn.. now I'm even more confused with my own memory

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the Australian VR horror film [Subterano](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0255623/) from 2003.

> Eleven souls, trapped in an underground carpark, are attacked by deadly, remote controlled toys. Only a few will survive.

People being killed one by one, [Daft Punk helmet guy](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/0bMAAOxyFPNSHszi/s-l400.jpg) attached to a big cable, the pink-haired girl with knee-high socks attacked in a toilet, it's all there.

Here's a short trailer: